# find index of subset of list containing strings

Tags: python, nlp, timestamp, nltk, speech

I am working on NLP in python and I have converted audio files to text and then found time offsets against each word spoken in speech, and then stored words in `wordlist` plus the time  in `timelist`.

I have three lists, 1st list named `strlist`, 2nd named `wordlist`, 3rd named `timelist`
strlist contains phrase lets say

```
strlist = ["in", "the", "family"]
```

wordlist contains paragraph or lets say sentences

```
wordlist = ["there", "are", "few", "things", "to", " be", "in", "the", "family", "means"]
```

`timelist` contains some time values against each word stores in `wordlist` lets suppose

```
timelist=[2,3,4,5,7,4,8,9,5,3]
```

I want to know if `strlist`'s phrase (consists of few words) is present in `wordlist` or not. If it is present then I want to check the time values stores in `timelist` against those words.

```
 from pathlib import Path
  import io
 from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('proven- 
mystery-310205-f04fb2ab3d69.json')
str='in my family'
strlist = list(str.split(" "))
timelist=[]
wordlist=[]
strlist.append("")
for i in strlist:
  print(i)
speech_file = Path("C:/Users/Tani/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/t.wav")
print("Start")

from google.cloud import speech_v1 as speech

print("checking credentials")

client = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)

print("Checked")
with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

print("audio file read")

audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

print("config start")
config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
     encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
     language_code='en-US',
     audio_channel_count=2,
     enable_separate_recognition_per_channel=True,
     enable_word_time_offsets=True)
 print("Recognizing:")
 response = client.recognize(config=config,audio=audio)

 print("Recognized")

 for result in response.results:
     alternative = result.alternatives[0]
     #print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))

  for word_info in alternative.words:
       word = word_info.word
       start_time = word_info.start_time
       end_time = word_info.end_time
       wordlist.append(word)
       timelist.append(start_time.seconds)
 print(str)
 for a, b in zip(wordlist,timelist):
      print('Word: {}, time: {}'.format(
      a,
      b))
 print("findout time")


 for s in strlist:
    if s in wordlist:
       position = wordlist.index(s)
       time_s = timelist[position]
       print(f"Word: '{s}', Time: {time_s}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a code that does the job. It can be improved, of course:

```
strlist = ["in", "the", "family"]
wordlist = ["there", "are", "few", "things", "to", " be", "in", "the", "family", "means"]
timelist=[2,3,4,5,7,4,8,9,5,3]

for s in strlist:
    if s in wordlist:
        position = wordlist.index(s)
        time_s = timelist[position]
        print(f"Word: '{s}', Time: {time_s}")
```

And the output is:

```
Word: 'in', Time: 8
Word: 'the', Time: 9
Word: 'family', Time: 5
```

There's another code that produces the same results, but it works only if you don’t have repeated words:

```
strlist = ["in", "the", "family"]
wordlist = ["there", "are", "few", "things", "to", " be", "in", "the", "family", "means"]
timelist=[2,3,4,5,7,4,8,9,5,3]

map = {word: time for word, time in zip(wordlist, timelist)}
for s in strlist:
    print(f"Word: '{s}', Time: {map[s]}")
```

Feel free to test both.

Comment: the answer you have provided is not working for me properly as it doesn't provides correct time

Comment: This code is returning 8, 9 and 5 for the words "in", "the", and "family". 
I'm not seeing an error. The code is working right, unless your lists are wrong.

I edited the print line to show the information more clearly.

Comment: as i told in description that i am supposing these lists they are not real, in real words can be repeated in the lists.For example on 2 index if there is word "in" on  it will give time of that "in" rather that of on index 6 which is wrong

Comment: can you please explain 2nd code which you have  provide i am not understanding it that how its working

Comment: You have to provide a coherent mapping rule between the `wordlist` and `timelist`. 

Your description implicitly says that if "in" is at index 6 in `wordlist`, then we have to take index 6 in `timelist`. That's make sense. If it's not true, you have to provide a different mapping rule in description, otherwise it'll be impossible to solve the problem. What should be the real time for the word "in" in your example?

Comment: In the 2nd code I built a python dictionary to store the mapping between `wordlist` and `timelist`.
The dictionary I built looks like: `{"there": 2, "are": 3,  ... , "in": 8}`.

So, now you can access the time for a word using `map[word]`. For example, if you want the time for the word "in", you can use `map["in"]` and it'll return the corresponding value. 

So, the first step is build a coherent mapping rule between words and time. Then,  you can use a dictionary to store this mapping (it's much better and efficient than use lists).

Comment: basically i have converted audio files into text and findout word_time_offset through google cloud API and store all the words and there corresponding time and phrase taken from user and store it in a list so words can be repeat in that sense because speech can be anything

Comment: You can't use the 2nd code because word repetition. 
But I can't see any problem with the first code... words can repeat and the speech time can vary... and it will work.
If you have a word list like this: `wordlist = ["there", "are", "there"]`, where the word "there" is repeated, you can store the speech time this way: `timelist=[2,3,4]`, meaning that, in the first time "there" had speech time = 2, and in the second time, the same word had  speech time = 4.
Time list must have the same length as wordlist, because for each speech word you have a corresponding speech time.

Comment: in speech word can be repeated many times so as the time becuase may be word there is repeated 3 times there are, there is, there you go,and firstly it was spoken on 3 sec then 15 sec and then 30 sec in audio speech so now if we have strlist containing there you go in that case your code will give time 3 sec while checking first word there rather it should give 30sec

Comment: your code is checking eachword of strlist and then giving time accarding to that word rather i want to compare whole strlist not just a single word by word comparison kindly provide code for this if you understand my point

Comment: i need help please somebody help me